# How to get TABLE Type return type from Oracle Stored procedure in Mule4?

Tags: mule, dataweave

Hi I am trying to call a stored procedure in Oracle which return a TABLE type .  This is my Package

```
create or replace PACKAGE        "PKG_LOGIC_SERVICE" AS

TYPE ll_ret_rec IS RECORD (
    ll_attribute      loan_logic.attribute%TYPE,
    ll_ret_value      loan_logic.ret_value%TYPE,
    ll_edit_type      loan_logic.edit_type%TYPE,
    ll_applic_type    loan_logic.application_type%TYPE,
    ll_rule_order     loan_logic.rule_order%TYPE,
    ll_db_field_name  loan_logic.db_field_name%TYPE,
    ll_xpath_name     loan_logic.xpath_name%TYPE,
    ll_loan_id        loans.loan_id%TYPE,
    ll_process_id     NUMBER(12)
);
TYPE ll_ret_table IS
    TABLE OF ll_ret_rec;
PROCEDURE pr_loan_logic_check (
    in_loan_id        IN   loans.loan_id%TYPE,
    in_trans_id       IN   NUMBER,
    as_errm           OUT  VARCHAR2,
   -- curr_cursor_out   IN OUT  SYS_REFCURSOR,
    ll_ret_table_out  OUT  PKG_LOGIC_SERVICE.ll_ret_table
);

PROCEDURE pr_insert_pricing_table (
    in_loan_id     IN   loans.loan_id%TYPE,
    ad_cur_seq_no  OUT  NUMBER,
    ad_retval      OUT  NUMBER,
    as_errm        OUT NOCOPY VARCHAR2
);

END PKG_LOGIC_SERVICE;
```

The way i am trying to call from Mule is like below

```
{call PKG_LOGIC_SERVICE.pr_loan_logic_check(776665544,987,:as_errm,:ll_ret_table_out)}
```

But i am getting an error

```
wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'pr_loan_logic_check'
```

My XML  SP portion is

```
<db:stored-procedure doc:name="Stored procedure" doc:id="ffc0e3aa-193a-4e86-91df-a52562e5acc4" 
config-ref="DB_CONFIG">
        <db:sql ><![CDATA[{call 
 PKG_LOGIC_SERVICE.pr_loan_logic_check(776665544,987,:as_errm,:ll_ret_table_out)}]]></db:sql>
        <db:output-parameters >
            <db:output-parameter key="ll_ret_table_out" customType="TABLE" />
            <db:output-parameter key="as_errm" type="VARCHAR" />
        </db:output-parameters>
    </db:stored-procedure>
```

What is the mistake i am doing and How mule know about the custom type TABLE while calling the procedure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to fix it by following this Article

https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Calling-Oracle-Stored-Procedure-with-User-Defined-Types-UDT-as-IN-OUT-or-IN-OUT-Parameters-in-Mule-4-x

Answer (score 0):

The output type should be "CURSOR" instead of "TABLE"

```
<db:output-parameter key="ll_ret_table_out" customType="CURSOR" />
```

Also, I'm not sure if the SP call works with just 3 parameters. Did you try it on an external SQL client?

You may want to read about [Oracle UDT](https://docs.mulesoft.com/db-connector/1.9/database-connector-udt-stored-procedure) too.

Comment: CURSOR also its  giving same eeror message, but why its has to be cursor , In procedure its defined as type of TABLE .
TYPE ll_ret_table IS TABLE OF ll_ret_rec;

Comment: The call have 4 Arguments not 3 
pr_loan_logic_check(776665544,  987,  :as_errm,  :ll_ret_table_out)